# I want to learn more mathematics

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

I'm a computer science student, but I'm not satisfied with my math skills.

I need suggestions on how to improve my math skills, including books for beginners and the like.

Comment: What does this has to do with number theory??

Answer (score 2):

I am also learning mathematics but I have few suggestions to you as a fellow learner.

1. Solve as much problems you can. Mathematics is not a spectator sport. You need to get your hands dirty, scribble things on paper etc.
2. Read "How to Solve it" by G. Polya and "What is Mathematics" by Courant . These books will help you in developing some interests which is most important thing. You may also like to read "Letters to young mathematician " by Ian Stewart.